# Oscillating blocktime issue

Tags: timestamp, block-interval, besu, hyperledger

I have three private blockchain networks:

1. `production`
2. `development`
3. `QA`

`production` and `QA` both have blockTime of 10 seconds and are behaving as expected.
When I read their block timestamps, there is always 10 seconds difference between consecutively minted blocks.

Example:

```
block1.timestamp = 1666621000

block2.timestamp = 1666621010
```

However, when it comes to the `development` network, the blockTimes can range from 13 all up to 29 seconds.

I wanted to ask if anybody else ever experienced anything similar.

NOTE1: I am developing on `Hyperleger Besu`

EDIT: Here are the screenshots from Grafana (the tool we use for monitoring our networks)

**First screenshot** shows `CPU` usage skyrocketing in days prior. Once the `CPU` usage per node reached upper limits, the `blockTime` began rising too.

[image: CPU usage per node]

**Second screenshot** shows the rise in average `blockTime` over the last few days (From 10s per block, to 38seconds, and it is **still** slowly growing)

[image: BlockTime]

Interested if anyone else experienced something like this.

**1.** Validator nods suddenly require more `CPU` resources

**2.** After CPU resources reach their limit, the `blockTime` goes up.

NOTE2: We did restart one of the nodes to test what would happen, and it did help a bit, but we want to understand the cause of this.

Comment: I would say your setup probably not powerful enough or not enough memory. Also you do not indicate much about your network. It may vary a lot depending on what consensus algorithm you use.

Comment: We are using proof of authority.  Does that give you any idea on what might have caused this.